# Glide version 4, the Glide.clear(ImageView) in not there anymore

Tags: android-glide

In a recyclerView's adapter, when OnBindViewHolder() is called and the viewHolder from the recycler pool is passed in for this position, and the imageView will be updated with image for this position or no image at all for this position.

For the case of there is no image at this position,  with Glide version 3, this `clear()` is called to clear the imageView:

```
Glide.clear(this.theImageView)
```

But when upgrade to Glide 9, it does not have this `clear(ImageView)` anymore.

What is the right way to clear the image of the ImageView with Glide 9?

**update**: the solution

```
fun ImageView.clear() {
   Glide.with(this.context).clear(this)
}
```

does not work, see Glide's comment:

```
<p> Note that this will only work if {@link View#setTag(Object)} is not called on this view outside of Glide. </p>
```

```
/**
   * Cancel any pending loads Glide may have for the view and free any resources that may have been
   * loaded for the view.
   *
   * <p> Note that this will only work if {@link View#setTag(Object)} is not called on this view
   * outside of Glide. </p>
   *
   * @param view The view to cancel loads and free resources for.
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if an object other than Glide's metadata is put as the view's
   *                                  tag.
   * @see #clear(Target)
   */
  public void clear(@NonNull View view) {
    clear(new ClearTarget(view));
  }
```

Comment: So did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

For java

```
 Glide.with(context).clear(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

found a solution, adding a kotlin extension solves the problem:

```
fun ImageView.clear() {
   Glide.with(this.context).clear(this)
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but raised this error : You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting

Comment: yes, see that when called setTag() on that imagView, what is the solution then?   ```<p> For Glide to function correctly, Glide must be the only thing that calls {@link
   * View#setTag(Object)}. If the tag is cleared or put to another object type, Glide will not be
   * able to retrieve and cancel previous loads which will not only prevent Glide from reusing
   * ...... ```